# Binary representation of small float values in Python

Tags: python, floating-point, binary, floating

How can I convert small float values such as *1.942890293094024e-15* or *2.8665157186802404e-07* to binary values in Python?

I tried [GeeksforGeek's solution](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-convert-floating-to-binary/), however, it does not work for values this small (I get this error:  **ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.942890293094024e-15'**).

The code looks like this so far:

```
def float_bin(number, places = 3): 

    # split() seperates whole number and decimal  
    # part and stores it in two seperate variables 
    whole, dec = str(number).split(".") 

    # Convert both whole number and decimal   
    # part from string type to integer type 
    whole = int(whole) 
    dec = int (dec) 

    # Convert the whole number part to it's 
    # respective binary form and remove the 
    # "0b" from it. 
    res = bin(whole).lstrip("0b") + "."

    # Iterate the number of times, we want 
    # the number of decimal places to be 
    for x in range(places): 

        # Multiply the decimal value by 2  
        # and seperate the whole number part 
        # and decimal part 
        whole, dec = str((decimal_converter(dec)) * 2).split(".") 

        # Convert the decimal part 
        # to integer again 
        dec = int(dec) 

        # Keep adding the integer parts  
        # receive to the result variable 
        res += whole 

    return res 


# Function converts the value passed as 
# parameter to it's decimal representation 
def decimal_converter(num):  
  while num > 1: 
      num /= 10
  return num
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Can you copy-paste the code (min. working example) and the error message?

Comment: I get this error: **ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.942890293094024e-15'**. I am putting the code to the question.

Comment: Check out this [trinket](https://trinket.io/python3/8934ea47a2). You might need to perform some tweaks.

Comment: I tweaked the code you sent and it works! Thank you very much! @kartoon

Comment: Good job! It'll be amazing if you post answer to your own question to help others in need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some consultation, I found a good [piece of code](https://trinket.io/python3/8934ea47a2) that solves my problem. I just had to apply some little tweaks on it (making it a function, removing automatic input requests etc.).

Huge thanks to @kartoon!

Answer (score -1):

One problem I see is with `str(number).split(".")`. I've added a simple hack before that: `number = "{:30f}".format(number)` so that there is no `e` in number. Though, I'm not sure if the result is correct.

Comment: When I do this I see 1.942890293094024e-15 (number) as 0.000000 :(

Comment: Seems reasonable to me. 2e-15 is very close to 0.

Comment: However, I can't do approximation. I need a binary expression rather than 0. Also when add this snippet to code I get this error: **ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)**

Comment: Most probably `decimal_converter()` returns int instead of float. Please better describe your current problem.